# Getting "subscript out of range" error when trying to insert/display array output

Tags: excel, vba

I have an .mdb database and I'm querying it in my macro. I'm putting the query results in an array. I want to show them in my Outlook body, but it gives me an error:

> subscript out of range

```
Public Sub sendNotifForm4()

Dim userArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer



        Dim objOutlook As Object
        Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient

            Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = OpenDatabase("C:/Users/FTK1187/Desktop/eArchiveMaster.mdb", False, False, ";")

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(Name:="SELECT userName FROM userTable WHERE flag = 'NO'")
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rs.EOF

            userArray = rs.GetRows
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

    x = (UBound(userArray, 1) - LBound(userArray, 1) + 1)

        'On Error Resume Next

           Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") ' Determine if Outlook is open
           If Err <> 0 Then 'If Not open it
              Call Shell(SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) & "OUTLOOK.EXE")
           End If

        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            objOutlookMsg.Subject = " E - Archiving User Account Approvements "
            objOutlookMsg.Body = objOutlookMsg.Body & "Dear Admin," & _
                                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please approve this user accounts" & _
                                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine
                     For i = 0 To UBound(userArray)
                            objOutlookMsg.Body = objOutlookMsg.Body & "User Name:"
                            objOutlookMsg.Body = objOutlookMsg.Body & userArray(i)
                            objOutlookMsg.Body = objOutlookMsg.Body & "Approval : NO"

                     Next i
                            objOutlookMsg.Body = objOutlookMsg.Body & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Best Regards"

'admin table loop here:

               Set objOutlookRecip = objOutlookMsg.Recipients.Add("Mustafa.Demir@pw.utc.com") '
objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

'Call sendMail(objOutlookMsg, objOutlookRecip, "Repair Engineering", olTo)

            objOutlookMsg.Send

            Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
            Set objOutlook = Nothing


End Sub
```

I tried to use `objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody`, but I can't run it correctly. Can you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: IS your array unidimensional or bidimensional? You are using `userArray(i)`, which is used only if the array is unidimensional. But I think method `GetRows` will import complete recordset into array, creating an Array bidimensional with 2 indexes (first one would be row number, and second one would be column number). Have you tried using something like `userArray(i, 1)` where `1` is the column (field) you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.getrows
```

'The function .getRows return's a two-dimensional Array (0,0) , 
' try to use the variable inspector to see what is going on with the array UserArray

```
For i = 0 To UBound(userArray)
       objOutlookMsg.Body = objOutlookMsg.Body & "User Name:"
       objOutlookMsg.Body = objOutlookMsg.Body & userArray(0, i)
       objOutlookMsg.Body = objOutlookMsg.Body & "Approval : NO"
Next i
```

Comment: OK, it's working but there is little problem. My database has two records that the flag=NO but it gives me one record.

Comment: Take a look in the rs object , are the rs.recordCount = 2? or 1 ? , Are u sure that your query returns 2 records ? , if yes , are u using the iterator "i" the right way ?... take a look in your variables , if i helped u upvot

Comment: My query return 2 records, I can't do it yet but I'm working on it. thank u for your answer.